# What is ATP and why is it said to be a source of energy?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, energy

Is ATP a molecule or a kind of energy. When I studied the active transport, it's said the ATP would release energy to change the carrier protein shape. So confused.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Energy can't release energy, because energy is... energy. Energy has to be contained otherwise it's useless. You can't pour a handful of charged electrons in your pc can you? Plants can't store rays of sunlight in their leaves, right? They store.sun energy as glucose later to be converted into ATP to release energy. Google ATP: first line [ATP wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate): *called the "**molecular** unit of (...) intracellular energy transfer*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too trivial

Comment: Because there is so much slack usage in relation to ATP and energy, it might be worth reformulating the question title, e.g. "What is ATP and why is it said to be a source of energy?" And then reworking the question to its essentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATP is adenosine 5'-triphosphate, a molecule consisting of the base adenine attached to which is attached a ribose (at its 1 position) and (at its 5 position) three phosphates, alpha-, beta- and -gamma (see edited image from Wikipedia below). The *(Gibbs) free energy of hydrolysis* of the phosphoanydride bonds between the gamma and beta phosphates and betweeen the alpha and beta phosphates is relatively large in terms of biological reactions. This means that coupling of the hydrolysis of ATP (usually, but not always, to ADP — adenosine 5'-diphosphate) to a reaction that is energetically unfavourable can often produce an overall reaction that is energetically favourabe (has an overall negative free energy change). Enzymes have evolved to catalyse such coupled reactions involving ATP.

Although ATP is often referred to as having ‘energy-rich bonds’ this is not the best way of thinking of things. First, and perhaps most important, you cannot think of energy in abstract, and even referring to ‘breaking a bond’ is insufficient. One is talking about free energy *change* which must relate to a specific reaction, in this case hydrolysis:

ATP + H<sub>2</sub>O → ADP + PO<sub>4</sub><sup>3–</sup> *or less frequently* ATP + H<sub>2</sub>O → AMP + pyrophosphate

Second the free energy change is only ‘high’ in relation to cellular reactions. Third the energy is only of any use if it can be *coupled* to these reactions (or processes like active cation transport).

It is perhaps better to refer to ATP as having a ‘high phosphate group transfer potential’.

The coupling of the hydrolysis of ATP to mechanical processes like muscle contraction or the change of shape of transporters (if that is what happens) is more complex, but obeys essentially the same principles. The  ATP hydrolysis reaction with its favourable negative change in free energy is coupled to the  mechanical process with its unfavourable positive free energy change.

**Further Information**

> ATP and Free Energy: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9903/#A295
>
> ‘High Energy Phosphate’: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-energy_phosphate
>
> ATP and Cation Transport: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9847/

[image: ATP]