# Use of ADP hydrolysis for driving energy-requiring processes?

Tags: biochemistry, energy-metabolism

The free energy of the hydrolysis of the β-γ phosphoanhydride bond of ATP is used to drive energy-requiring biological process such as chemical synthesis, movement, ion transport and production of light.

However the chemical structure of the α-β phosphoanhydride bond of ADP appears very similar, but I am unaware of instances where its free energy of hydrolysis is used in a similar way. Is this theoretically possible, and are there any actual examples?

Comment: I have edited your question as the term "potential energy" is not generally used in relation to biochemical reactions, the expression "used for energy" is imprecise, and the title poses as different question to the body of your question.: ADP can be used for other purposes (as a regulatory molecule, for example) besides driving energy-requiring reaction, but it appears that it is the latter that you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

**It *is* theoretically possible**
[image: ATP and ADP structures compared]
The structures of ATP and ADP are shown above, with the phosphate groups designated α, β and γ. The value of the Gibbs standard free energy of hydrolysis of the α–β phosphoanhydride bond of ADP is [similar](https://vrchemistry.chem.ox.ac.uk/chapter22/page29.htm) to that of the β–γ phosphoanhydride bond of ATP at approx. 30 kJ per mol. Hence it is *theoretically* possible to couple the hydrolysis of the α–β phosphoanhydride bond of ADP to an energy-requiring process and produce an overall negative ΔG.
(The reader may wish to consult an external source — e.g. [this previous SE Biology answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44334/what-is-atp-and-why-is-it-said-to-be-a-source-of-energy/44341#44341) — if unfamiliar with a chemical account of the popular but imprecise idea of ATP as a “source of energy”.)

**The hydrolysis of the analogous bond of *ATP* is so used**
Most reactions and processes for which ATP provides the driving free energy change involve the hydrolysis of the β–γ phosphoanhydride bond in the reaction:
`ATP → ADP + Pi`
However in several synthetic processes the energy is provided from the hydrolysis of the α–β phosphoanhydride bond in the reaction:
`ATP → AMP + PPi`
These include RNA synthesis (to form a phosphodiester bond) and amino-acyl tRNA synthesis (to form the aminoacyl bond, which itself provides the energy to drive peptide bond formation).

**Examples of ADP hydrolysis driving energy-requiring reactions?**
Although this may merely reflect my ignorance, *I know of no reactions* of the sort:
`ADP → AMP + Pi`
where the energy of hydrolysis is used to form a chemical bond etc. 
So, although I may be proved wrong, **my** answer is **NO**. But…

…a *possible* exception — not producing inorganic phosphate — is the [adenylate kinase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenylate_kinase) reaction, for which the overall standard free energy change is near zero:
`2 ADP ⇔ ATP + AMP`
This could be considered as using the energy of hydrolysis of the α–β phosphoanhydride of one of the molecules of ADP to form the β–γ phosphoanhydride bond of ATP. This is thought to be important in the regulation of glycolysis, the AMP produced serving as a signal for the requirement of energy and acting as an activator of the enzyme phosphofructokinase.

**Why — or why not?**
“Why” questions are dangerous in biology, as there is a tendency to argue that the way things are are the way they must be; and there are generally no tests of hypotheses in support of such a view. Nor did the original poster ask why. But with the strict understanding that what follows is *just speculation*, I offer these thoughts in support of my generally negative answer:

- [I have argued previously](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11286/why-is-atp-the-preferred-choice-for-energy-carriers/50928#50928) that an NTP (ATP — perhaps by chance)
  developed as the “universal energy currency” because it was already
  involved in RNA synthesis in the hypothetical RNA world. Clearly this
  requires hydrolysis of the α–β phosphoanhydride bond of a nucleoside
  phosphate molecule. The argument for ATP over ADP would be that the
  pyrophosphate produced in the former process is further hydrolysed to
  inorganic phosphate by pyrophosphates, and the irreversibility of the
  reaction (heat is produced) is important to prevent RNA synthesis
  reversing. As NTPs had to be synthesized anyway, they could also be
  used for other purposes, but it was energetically more efficient to
  hydrolyse the β–γ phosphoanhydride bond if irreversibility was not
  crucial (e.g. the product removed).
- Once ATP became fixed as the energy currency, metabolism was tuned
  for its production and, later regulation. Thus the development of
  systems for anaerobic and aerobic synthesis of ADP would not have
  conferred any advantage on an organism. When regulatory systems
  developed in involving the relative concentrations of ATP, ADP and
  AMP (as mentioned above), using ADP to drive reactions would have
  been disruptive.